# Поддержка ссылочной целостности

Tags: oracle

Как известно, Oracle не создает индексов на внешние ключи.

Вопрос: у меня есть две таблицы `Master`, `Detail`, из `Detail` проброшен внешний ключ `ON CASCADE` на `Master`. При удалении записи из `Master` я получу FULL SCAN по `Detail` для поиска всех подлежащих удалению записей или у Оракла есть какие-то свои способы для быстрого поиска подчиненных записей?

Comment: А что вам мешает создать эти индексы самостоятельно?

Comment: @Viktorov Ничто не мешает. Но вопрос ни о том "как сделать", а о том "как работает СУБД"

Comment: @Viktorov и к sql вопрос не имеет ни малейшего отношения

Comment: У Оракла нет никаких хитрых способов кроме индексов для такого поиска. Единственный вариант - создать индексы. PS на мой взгляд `sql` метка все же уместна, т.к. речь о том, что происходит при работе `SQL` запросов. Ну и как минимум так вопрос увидят те, кто подписаны на `sql`, но не подписаны на `oracle` отдельно. Вопрос конечно ваш, решать вам

Comment: @Viktorov как работает sql я знаю. Меня интересует как работает оракл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Других способов быстрого поиска кроме индексов нет.

Мало того, что получится full scan, так база еще и заблокирует всю таблицу `Detail` на время операции. ([Oracle 18c Database Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-261F98F8-F7B4-49A9-9BE8-11F2B1F4609B)):

> **Locks and Unindexed Foreign Keys**
>   The database acquires a full table lock on the child table when no index exists on the foreign key column of the child table, and a session modifies a primary key in the parent table (for example, deletes a row or modifies primary key attributes) or merges rows into the parent table.

При параллельных изменениях это приведет к deadlock.